Convert "AAAAAABBBBCCCDD" to "A6B4C3D2" in Dataweave
working on a DataWeave transformation and need some help converting a string to a compressed format. Here’s the requirement:
Input :
{ "string":"AAAAAABBBBCCCDD" }
Desired Output:
{ "string":A6B4C3D2 }
In the output, I want to count consecutive characters and represent them in a compressed format.

The output is in how many of each letter was found such as A6 is the first value, since the string starts with AAAAAA.  Maybe you could count the values and display them?

Explain what are you trying to do. How the output relates to the input?

please Always Ask question with proper details. and share if you have tried anything to able to help you better

This comes across like a "send me codez" question.  If this is formal or informal "homework" you should show us what you have tried ... instead of just asking for the solution.  Please see: How do I ask and answer homework questions?  ("I am new to X" is never a valid excuse not to try.)

What should be the output if string is AABBCAA should it be A2B2C1A2 or A4B2C1 ?

@HarshankBansal, For input AABBCAA, output should be A4B2C1 . However, I would also like to know what would be the data weave for A2B2C1A2...

@aaakheel6 did you check the solution provided in Answer Section?

@AnuragSharma,
Thanks a ton for providing the solution, it worked just fine as expected. However, i felt the solution got little over my head as i am a beginner. :)

You can get the desired output by grouping the continuous same characters and then concatenate each character with its counting. check below DataWeave Script
here input is
{
    "inputString": "AAAAAABBBBCCCDD"
}

solution to get desired output is:
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var test = payload.inputString groupBy ($)
---
{
"String": (keysOf(test) map($ ++ sizeOf(test[$]))) joinBy ""
}

below is the DataWeave playground screen shot

